# Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\frac{s(n)}{d(n)}\geq \sqrt n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\frac{s(n)}{d(n)}\geq \sqrt n$$ where $s(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$ and $d(n) = \sum_{d|n} 1$.

Being honest, study some time arithmetic functions, and can not enchegar a means of solving this demonstration ... I searched the internet but nothing has been found (in Portuguese) so I could solve a this.

Comment: I take it $s(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$, right?

Comment: @IgorRivin $p + 1 \geq 2 \cdot \sqrt{p}$ is true always. Indeed, $(\sqrt{p} - 1)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @PabloRotondo You respond too quickly :)

Comment: Exactly @PabloRotondo

Comment: @marcelolpjunior:  Just a minor note on notation - Usually, we denote the sum of divisors $\sigma$ as
$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}{d}.$$
We then denote the aliquot sum $s$ as
$$s(n) = \sigma(n) - n.$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Take the natural pairing of the divisor and show that $ \frac{d + \frac{n}{d} } {2} \geq \sqrt{n}$.

Deal with the case where $n$ is a perfect square separately, for completeness.

Comment: I do not understand how to do this using my demonstration.
I do not see a beginning!

Comment: Could more detail, please?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior We always have $\dfrac{a+b}2\geqslant \sqrt{ab}$. Let $a=d$ and $b=n/d$.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), any natural number N can be written as a unique product of powers of prime numbers, or $N=\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^kp_j^{n_j}$ . It can then be shown that

[image]

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties) and [here](http://www.planetmath.org/productofdivisorsfunction) for proofs of these two relations. Then use them together with the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), and write $\displaystyle{\frac{D_S}{d(N)}\geqslant\sqrt[d(N)]{D_P}=\sqrt[d(N)]{N^\frac{d(N)}2}=N^\frac12=\sqrt N}$ . QED.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{s(n)}{d(n)}$ is the arithmetical mean of the divisors of $n$ (Which means you can use AM-GM). However, i managed to improve the bound to $\frac{s(n)}{d(n)}\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{n}-1$ by using $d(n)\leq 2\sqrt n$ and proving: $s(n)\geq\sqrt n.d(n)+(\sqrt n-1)^2$
If you are interested about these bounds, for composite $n>4$ one can prove that $\frac{3}{8}n+1\geq\frac{s(n)}{d(n)}\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{n}-1$

Comment: Isn't $d(n) \leq 2\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. Edited.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. If the bound can be improved why retain equality in the original inequality?

Comment: Because in the original inequality, the equality holds when $n=1$ and in that case, $\sqrt n>\frac{3}{2}\sqrt n-1$(Solving this yields $n<4$) so the new inequality isn't actually "improved" for all $n$.